# how can I convert a string '1:05" to a time stamp?

Tags: python, timestamp, data-conversion

I need to add enroute time (1:05) to a depature time (which has been converted to a time stamp) to get the arrival time. how can I convert 1:05 to a time stamp?

Comment: what does 1:05 stand for 1:05 can be 1 minute 5 seconds; it can also be 1:50am? Do you want to add 1 minute, 5 seconds to the departure time?

Comment: Hi @MEdwin, here 1 is the hour and 05 is minutes. '1:05' is actually the difference between the arrival and departure time of a flight.

Comment: @MEdwin, the data is something like this..

 (departure time)1/7/2016 0:27 
       (arrival time to next airport)- missing data
 Enroute time 1:05
here, I wish to add enroute time to departure time and get the arrival time. I hope i am a bit clearer now.

Comment: okay, I have modified it below. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

If 1 hour and 5 minutes is the time difference or `time_delta` you don't need it as a time stamp.

Make a time delta:

```
time_period = datetime.timedelta(hour = 1, minutes = 5)
```

Then you can add it to datetimes:

```
when = datetime.datetime.today()
when + time_period
```

This gives a new datetime:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 14, 12, 19, 33, 499846)
```

Comment: Hi @doctorlove,
Thank you your your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use `datetime` and `timedelta` to add the required amount.

see a mockup date a with 1 hour 5 minutes added.

```
import datetime
departuretime = datetime.datetime(2016,7,1,0,27,0) #(departure time)1/7/2016 0:27
#timedelta(days=999999999, hours=23, minutes=59, seconds=59, microseconds=999999) .
enroutetime=datetime.timedelta(hours = 1,minutes=5) #Enroute time 1:05 : add 1 hour, 5 minutes
arrivaltime = departuretime + enroutetime
print departuretime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print arrivaltime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

result:

```
01/07/2016 00:27
01/07/2016 01:32
```